# How would I run a script where the .exe runs in one location and the script in another location?

Tags: powershell, directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

After searching for the question, I didn't see anything outside of running multiple scripts in one file.

I'm trying to figure out how to run a script where the script lives in one directory and the .exe file that the script is running lives in another one.

If you're curious, the ask is coming from a person that stores hundreds of scripts in a separate location from any executable files. I was asked specifically to help with the script itself on this particular project. I'm not well versed in script writing, so I thought I would reach out here and see.

Below is the current code in the script that runs perfectly. The other parts of the script are specific to the program being installed and aren't relevant to actually starting the install.

I'm using Powershell to run this.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$currentpath\ClientSetup_111.exe" -ArgumentList $InstCmdLine -Wait -PassThru
```

Comment: You can write the path to the exe like `c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe` and powershell will run it. Or if there are spaces, like `& 'C:\program files\paint.net\paintdotnet.exe'`

Comment: Thank you for that. It worked perfectly. I tried something else, but I overcomplicated it the first time I tried it.